# Pandas ".value_counts" while being used on a specific column in a datafile

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count the number of listing id's in a file. The following code however, retrieves every single row and does not count the number of times the id is repeated.

```
numrows = 1000
df3 = pd.read_csv('calendar_dec18.csv', delimiter=',', nrows = numrows)
df3.dataframeName = 'calendar_dec18.csv'



count = df3['listing_id'].value_counts

print(count)
```

[This is the output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hV7Q.png)

The output should look something like this:

listing_id   | count

12351       | 51

777184 | 23

etc.

Could a kind soul help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct Usage:

```
df3['listing_id'].value_counts().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks m8, mind if I get an explanation for this answer?

Comment: @seongjoon123 Not adding parenthesis does not run the code, it returns the function instance, `reset_index` converts the index to a column and makes it a dataframe, feel free to mark and upvote this if it helps.